# Remove Duplicates based on Separate Column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a weird problem at hand. In the picture below I want to remove 2nd row, since it is the same as the first row, but the employee ids are in different columns. Ideally, my final output should only have 1st and 3r row, or 2nd and 3rd row, since employee 1234567 and 111111 are already mentioned once. [image]

Comment: Row 2 is not a duplicate of row 1. You may see the same letters and numbers but they are in different fields and therefore are different data. EmployeeID 123456 != EmployeeID 111111.

Comment: This seems kinda odd. Depending which row you remove, you'll have different values in the other columns. Wouldn't that potentially mess up something else? Should employeeid 1234567 have a permission function of VR or of ISW?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the data as text into your request, please.

Comment: Is permission_function always equal to replacement_home_function and home_function always equal to replacement_permission_function? That would mean you are storing data redundantly which would violate database nomalization.

Comment: You consider the data in rows #1 and #2 duplicates, because they have the same data mirrored? But what about the expiration dates? They differ. Which one would you consider the correct one and why?

Comment: The expiration days are also the same for employee ids, yes I consider them duplicates because they are mirrored. 1234567 has expiration days for 153 and 1111111 has expiration for 57, which is the same you see in the next row for the respective employees.

Comment: Yes, try to select the data such that you get the same row for #1 and #2. You do this with case expressions, making the lower ID the employee and the higher ID the replacement employee. `select case when employeeid < replacementemployeeid then employeeid else replacementemployeeid end as emp_id, location, case when employeeid < replacementemployeeid then permission_function else replacement_permission_function end as perm_fct, ...`. Once you are there you can use `DISTINCT` to only get each combination once.

Answer (score 0):

For while I have less then 50 reputation, so I can't comment.

As for what you consider a duplicate row, it wasn't well defined. So I suppose a few things.

- When I want to enumerate the rows partition by some category, generally I make use of "Window functions", see the documentation:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html
  Probably, you'll use some of them:

  - `dense_rank`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_DENSE_RANK.html
  - `rank`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_RANK.html
  - `row_number`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_DENSE_RANK.html

For example, if you want enumerate rows by `location` column, you can use:

```sql
select  temp.*
from    (
    select  t.employeeid,
            t.location,
            row_number() over(partition by t.location) as number_of_row,
            [other_columns]
    from    [table] t
) temp
where   temp.number_of_row = 1
```

- You can also use other functions to return the value of another row. Some of them are:

  - `first_value`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html
  - `last_value`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_last_value.html
  - `lag`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html
  - `lead`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LEAD.html

```sql
select  temp.*
from    (
    select  t.*,
            lag(t.employeeid) over(partition by t.location order by t.expiration_days rows unbounded preceding) as lag_employeeid
    from    [table] t
) temp
where temp.lag_employeeid = temp.replacement_employeeid
```

You can do it so many ways. So, my advice is to understand how your data works and after that, choose some function that will help you to achieve the results needs.

I hope to help you.

Comment: To suggest a specific grouping potentially applicable to the question, I'll assume that rows 1 and 2 are considered duplicates by virtue of the two columns EMPLOYEEID and REPLACEMENT EMPLOYEEID.  On that assumption then a grouping that would work would be to group on the lowest of those two values: -

`row_number() over(partition by min(t.employeeid, t.replacement_employee_id) as number_of_row`